# I need to create a new object every time i click on a switch and delete it whenever i switch off

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

TLDR: i need to create a new object based on the selection from a switch on/off, if i click on, that specific project item is cloned to this new object, and so on

Got this question on reddit too -> https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/gpvnhv/need_help_creating_a_new_object_based_on_dropdown/

EDIT: I managed to filter the object for the dropdown component by only taking the clients, also got the filter for the projects to show in the flatlist. I need help by connecting both, that means, selecting a client from the dropdown and showing all the projects where they got the same id, like this

list of clients:

```
[
  {
    client: 'Microsoft', 
    idClient: '1'
  },
  {
    client: 'Google', 
    idClient: '0'
  }
]
```

list of projects:

```
[
  {
    project: 'Random stuff', 
    idClient: '1'
  }, 
  {
    project: 'Another Random stuff', 
    idClient: '1'
  }, 
  {
    project: 'GG', 
    idClient: '0'
  }
]
```

I've been suffering from a headache trying to figure it out this, i got an object with projects/clients, something like this.

```
items = [
 {
  client: 'Microsoft',
  idClient: 0,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'React Native App'
 },
 {
  client: 'Amazon',
  idClient: 1,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'ServerSide OPS'
 },
 {
  client: 'Microsoft',
  idClient: 0,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'AI Enhancer'
 },
 {
  client: 'Google',
  idClient: 4,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'Whatever Come Up With'
 },
 {
  client: 'KFC',
  idClient: 3,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'QR Reader'
 },     
]
```

This is just an example of my object, it has over 20 clients and some of these can have around 3 or 4 projects each, the whole object has around 60 to 70 items.

I got two screens, one which is the main, renders a calendar strip with custom views for each day, ok, here goes the interesting part, this is where my question goes from

The second screen is a dropdown menu where i select a client and list me all the projects based on that selected client, the huge problem is, since i'm unable to manipulate this object, first, i need a switch for each project, in order to select the ones i need to show on the first screen, and second, that new object needs to contain (aside from the item in the object), more stuff, like this {project: 'React Native App', hoursRemaining: 10, etc...}

here is the full code of the dropdown list screen

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, StatusBar, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, RefreshControl, FlatList, Platform} from 'react-native';
import { Header, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import ModalDropdown from 'react-native-modal-dropdown';
import Images from '../../Assets/values/images';
import { RFPercentage as rfp, RFValue as rfv } from 'react-native-responsive-fontsize';
import { heightPercentageToDP as hp, widthPercentageToDP as wp } from 'react-native-responsive-screen';
import styles from '../../Assets/values/styles/HoursReport/ClientsProyects/ClientsProyectsStyle';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import DataManager from '../../../Util/CrossUtils/DataManager';

export default class ClientsProyectsScreen extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      SeleccionClientes: '',
    }
  }

    items = [
 {
  client: 'Microsoft',
  idClient: 0,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'React Native App'
 },
 {
  client: 'Amazon',
  idClient: 1,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'ServerSide OPS'
 },
 {
  client: 'Microsoft',
  idClient: 0,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'AI Enhancer'
 },
 {
  client: 'Google',
  idClient: 4,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'Whatever Come Up With'
 },
 {
  client: 'KFC',
  idClient: 3,
  idProjectType: 1,
  projectType: 'traditional',
  title: 'QR Reader'
 },     
]

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(DataManager.ResponseProjectClient);
  }

  searchCliente = item => {
    var jsonData = item;
    var searchData = [];
    jsonData.forEach(element => {
      searchData.push(element.cliente);
    });
    return searchData;
  }

  searchProyecto = item => {

  }

  updateFav = item => {
   const newData = [...this.items[this.state.SeleccionClientes]];
   const updateItem = newData.find(x => x.key === item.key);
   updateItem.fav = !item.fav;
   const updatedArray = Object.assign(this.items);
   updatedArray[this.state.SeleccionClientes] = newData;
   this.setState({ items: updatedArray });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor="transparent" />
        <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa'}}/>
        {/*
        <Header
          backgroundImage={Images.header_nav}
          backgroundImageStyle={styles.HeaderImagenCP}
          leftComponent={
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
              <View><Image style={styles.HeaderHorizontal} source={Images.back}/></View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          }
          centerComponent={{text: 'Imputar horas', ellipsizeMode: 'clip', style: styles.HeaderHoursReportCP }}
          placement='center'
        />
        */}
        <View style={styles.ContainerBackground}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignSelf: 'flex-start', marginTop: hp('2.2%'), marginLeft: wp('6.3%')}}>
            <Text style={{
              fontSize: rfv(18),
              fontWeight: "500",
              fontStyle: "normal",
              textAlign: "left",
              color: "#707070"
            }}>Proyectos</Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{position: 'absolute', alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end', paddingBottom: hp('1%'), left: wp('90%')}} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
            <Image source={Images.close_modal}/>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <KeyboardAwareScrollView
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          enableOnAndroid={true}>
            {/*
            <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginRight: widthPercentageToDP('6.3%')}}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                <Image source={Images.close_modal}/>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            */}
            <View style={styles.Left}>
              <Text style={styles.TituloInputOnBlur}>Cliente</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.Center}>
              <ModalDropdown
                adjustFrame={style => {
                  style.top =(Platform.OS === 'ios' ? style.top : style.top - StatusBar.currentHeight);
                  return style;
                }}
                dropdownTextStyle={styles.dropdownTextStyle}
                dropdownTextHighlightStyle={styles.dropdownTextHighlightStyle}
                dropdownStyle={styles.dropdownStyle}
                defaultValue={'Seleccionar'}
                style={styles.dropStyle}
                textStyle={{
                  padding: 0,
                  margin: 0,
                  fontSize: rfv(16),
                  paddingVertical: hp('1.2%'),
                  fontWeight: 'normal',
                  fontStyle: 'normal',
                  textAlign: 'left',
                }}
                //onSelect={(index, value) => this.setState({SeleccionClientes: value})}
                //options={Object.keys(this.state.items)}
                onSelect={(index, value) => this.setState({SeleccionClientes: value})}
                options={Object.keys(this.items)}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
            {
              this.items[this.state.SeleccionClientes] != null ?
              <View>
                {
                  <FlatList
                    data={this.items[this.state.SeleccionClientes]}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => (
                      <ListItem
                        containerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#fafafa', width: wp('87.1%'), height: 64, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: hp('2.8%'), paddingHorizontal: 0}}
                        topDivider={false}
                        bottomDivider={true}
                        titleStyle={{
                          marginLeft: 0,
                          fontSize: rfv(16),
                          fontWeight: "normal",
                          fontStyle: "normal",
                          textAlign: "left",
                          color: "#707070"
                        }}
                        subtitleStyle={{
                          marginLeft: 0,
                          fontSize: rfv(14),
                          fontWeight: "normal",
                          fontStyle: "normal",
                          textAlign: "left",
                          color: "#c4c4c4"
                        }}
                        title={`${item.name}`}
                        subtitle={`ID ${item.key}`}
                        switch={{
                          trackColor: { false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" },
                          thumbColor: item.fav == true ? "#1062cc" : "#f4f3f4",
                          ios_backgroundColor: "#9e9e9e",
                          value: item.fav, 
                          onValueChange: () => this.updateFav(item)
                        }}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                }
              </View>
              :
              <View style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center'}}>
                <View style={{marginTop: hp('11%')}}>
                  <Image style={{marginBottom: hp('2.8%')}} source={Images.sad_face}/>
                </View>
                <Text style={{
                  fontSize: rfv(18),
                  fontWeight: "normal",
                  fontStyle: "normal",
                  textAlign: "left",
                  color: "#c4c4c4"
                }}>Sin proyectos activos</Text>
              </View>
            }
            </View>
          <View style={styles.BottomPush} />
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, you would need to make the abstraction between the `API response` and your `own data` which you can manipulate in order to add/remove data (ie: favorites).

In order for your dropdown to display an array of clients, you can use a helper function:

```js
const buildOptions = () => {
   return items.reduce((output, current) => {
      const { client } = current;
      output.push(client);
      return output;
}, []);
};
// returns: ['Walmart','Microsoft','Google']
```

Unfortunately, there is a limitation in `react-native-modal-dropdown` where you can't have the `idClient` in your options. Therefore, assuming your client names are unique, you can use a helper function that returns the client id from the name of the client, which gets fired in the `onChange` prop when the user makes a selection:

```js
const findClientIdByName = (name) => {
   return dropItems.find(item => item.client === name).idClient;
}
```

Now, when the user selects some favorite projects, the filtered list gets updated with a specific attribute that saves the switch state (ie: `fav: true`). That being said, initially, the `fav` property is `undefined`, which means that the switches will be automatically "OFF".

Then, you can create a function that returns the favorite projects:

```js
const favoriteProjects = list.filter(item => item.fav);
```

Finally, in your calendar view, you can build the final object like this:

```js
  const finalObject = { [selectedDate]: favoriteProjects };
```